# Rails dynamic default column value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

tl;dr: What is the Rails-y way to dynamically define model attribute / database column default?

---

I have a Devise-powered User model in my Rails app that has a custom column `organization_group_id` with a default of `2`.

```sh
vim db/schema.rb
```

reveals:

```rb
  # ...
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    # ...
    t.integer  "organization_group_id",  default: 2
    # ...
  end
  # ...
```

But *a* default value is assigned upon creation, but it is incorrect. The incorrect default (an `id` of `1`) was once the correct default, but I changed the data in the `OrganizationGroup` model, and the `id` `2` became correct. The above resulting schema file was generated correctly.

```rb
u = User.new
#<User id: nil, ... organization_group_id: 1,...>
```

Now, I can see why is happening -- in MYSQL, the default is incorrect, presumably a remnant from when the default was set in a different way (more on that in a minute).

```sql
DESCRIBE users;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ...                    | ...          | ..   | ... | ...     |                |
| organization_group_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 1       |                |
| ...                    | ...          | ..   | ... | ...     |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But my question is: Why didn't my last `rake db:migrate` work in this instance to overwrite the DB default? I'm guessing the answer has something to do with: My migration dynamically loads the default ID? If so, is there a preferred, Rails-y way to handle for dynamic defaults? Or perhaps I'm supposed to reload my database in order for Rails to re-run the column changes -- if so is there a way to do this without blowing away Production data?

```sh
vim db/migrate/20141125153344_add_default_value_to_user_organization_group.rb
```

reveals:

```rb
class AddDefaultValueToUserOrganizationGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if OrganizationGroup && !OrganizationGroup.where(group_name: "n/a").first.nil?
      change_column :users, :organization_group_id, :integer, :default => OrganizationGroup.where(group_name: "n/a").first.id
    else
      og = OrganizationGroup.new(group_name: "n/a")
      og.save!
      change_column :users, :organization_group_id, :integer, :default => og.id
    end
  end
end
```

Server details

- MYSQL Server version: 5.1.73
- ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
- Rails 4.1.4
- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: this behaviour is not quite good, because in future org gound is can be changed `:default => OrganizationGroup.where(group_name: "n/a").first.id`, but default value can be changed only during migration. (because it is not good way to change db in production)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Well, either by bug or design the default actually cannot be changed, otherwise the column value would have corrected. And anyway there is no CRUD on the Org Groups, so there is no chance to change them -- they are statically defined in `db:seed`

Comment: if default is fixed in DB, just use default value in model

Comment: like this `attribute :organization_group_id, Integer, default: 2`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, Is there no way to future proof the code to allow for a change to seeds + migration to correctly adjust? That I guess is what I'm after + I'm surprised that `db:migrate` doesn't handle for this (seems like a bug).

Comment: as far as I know `db:migrate` isn't look into **db/schema.rb**, just into migration folder. so you have to change the migration rule, or if default value depends on the DB state, use model's defaulting.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ The migration's content is changed -- it is dynamic. See edits.

Comment: Sam, you can change default value in DB, only by creating the new migration rule, which in your example change it to 2. But I strogly advice you create the default value in the model, because it depends on DB state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65834/discussion-between-sam-and--).